# nodejs how to send variable to tcpsocket

Tags: node.js

```
var comm = process.argv[2];
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST,function() {
    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
    client.write('global.comm \n',"binary");
});
```

I want to send variable comm to client.write();
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

client.write(comm "\n","binary");That's just ok,hahah!